# getting jquery working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have basic onclick functions* in my ruby on rails app, when i look at application.js, they're all available but in the frontend, when i actually click on the element, the function does not trigger, although when i try the HTML version equivalent, its working well.

The app has the jquery-rails Gem installed and just to double confirm, I also tried inserting the jquery.js file in the vendor folder, but neither of these solved it unfortunately

*example

```
$('#openSidebarButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#openSidebarButton').addClass('hidden');
    $('#sidebar').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: can you please show the code, that includes your javascript?

Comment: Are you using Turbolinks? Is your jQuery code wrapped in a `$(function() { ... })` or `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` wrapper?

Comment: thanks, the jquery on click functions are by themselves i.e outside the $(document).ready :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have the following in your application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: Thanks did try this although this did not solve it either, in my console, i get the following error: "Uncaught Error: jquery-ujs has already been loaded' :-(

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution..a bit silly of me but essentially, i did not include the function within document.ready, that's why it wasn't working :-)

to summarize, what i did was made the above mentioned on click within a function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   openSideBar();
});

function openSideBar {
$('#openSidebarButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#openSidebarButton').addClass('hidden');
    $('#sidebar').removeClass('hidden');
});
}
```